Properly Signing Out of Apache Wicket Application
We are looking for the correct Wicket APIs to call in order to properly sign out of an application. Throughout the years / going through Wicket upgrades, we've called a number of different org.apache.wicket.Session APIs and have never been completely sure which one(s) to invoke. We're looking for guidance to ensure we're doing this correctly.
Currently, we call both invalidateNow() and invalidate() which doesn't seem to be necessary at this point, and are looking for direction in which one should be preferred, and if we should be calling anything else.
Another consideration we are taking in to account is the fact that calling these methods does not result in our JSESSIONID getting re-generated by our application server (WebSphere), which we expect to happen to prevent session fixation. We see there are Wicket APIs to forcefully do this (changeSessionId()) but are unsure if this is necessary / if this should be happening naturally.
To summarize:

Which Wicket API(s) should we be calling to sign out a user?
Should we be calling changeSessionId() on login to prevent session fixation?
Are there any other considerations we should be accounting for?

Relevant stack: Wicket 8 / IBM WebSphere Application Server 9

invalidateNow() will invalidate the session immediately.
invalidate() will invalidate it at the end of the current request cycle, i.e. just before sending the response to the client.
In both cases the web server's HttpSession will be invalidated too. It is responsibility of the web server to invalidate the JSESSIONID by sending a cookie with negative value. If you have doubts I'd recommend you to register your own https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html and log/print whenever a session is created/destroyed.

Thank you very much for the information. We will opt to use invalidateNow(), and we will register a listener to get more detail surrounding JSESSIONID invalidation. If the session is getting destroyed, but our JSESSIONID is remaining the same, is this where we should consider leveraging changeSessionId() on login?

Using changeSessionId() on login is a good security design pattern! But why the JSESSIONID is not deleted - looks like a bug in your app (server?).

I apologize for the delay, we've been doing some troubleshooting to figure out why our session ID isn't changing. One thing that I'm noticing in our implementation is that our getHomePage has a lot of session logic - we get the session to check if the user is signed in / return the home page they should be directed to based on various properties. It feels like when getHomePage picks up the session, it ends up getting the previous session that we attempted to invalidate. Does it sound like this could be a part of the problem?

You should use Session.exists()! Session.get() works as "get or create".
it ends up getting the previous session - I have no good explanation how this is possible. As I recommended earlier - implement your own listener and see what the server/container does with the HttpSessions

Thanks again for all of your assistance - yes, our session listener output leads us to believe this is a behavior of our app server and not the application's implementation: sessionDestroyed is invoked upon logout, then, sessionCreated is invoked upon login and contains the same exact ID as the session that was just destroyed. We'll continue to explore solutions from the side of our app server config, but I think now we have a much better understanding of which Wicket APIs we should be leveraging for logout/login, as well as the app servers responsibilities. Thank you again!
